# Blocking certain features of a website like upload, comment

Tags: networking, browser

My new project criteria is providing only read only features of any website, for example like stack overflow,  I need to restricts users within my institution of option such as ask/comment, only read-only features should be available. 
Can anyone guide me with the direction to start, weather to make some browser plugin which will restricts users accordingly or something else.
Help really appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: How about not implementing the ask/comment feature at all, if you users should not be able to comment! However, if you want to have some part of users to be able to do that, you should implement a _permissions_ system. Say for example users can be either _admin_ or _regular user_.  Have I understood well?

Comment: In my organization certain websites are blocked, and reason behind it is people cannot upload some internal codes and all, so in my example above, stack-overflow is blocked in my organization, if it contains only read only access then it can be allowed inside, to overcome that I have to start a project which will unblock certain websites and selectively blocks any of its upload features.

Comment: Ah OK, I do understand better now :) Well, a browser plugin could be easily disabled. A wild idea I thought of is, to be able to post into websites or networks one has to be authenticated to that website (most of the times). You could setup an internal proxy through which all requests go and which filters out any cookies or authentication headers alongside those requests.